# Parallel process mysqldump to vagrant box

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, vagrant, mysql

This is bit of a tricky one. I am not quite sure where to post this. Should it be here on stack, over on the linux forum or on the DB exchange. I've posted it here anyway.

We have been looking into speeding up the mysql dump process within our office. All the developers have vagrant virtual machines for doing development, the vagrant machine runs the following :

- mysql version 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41
- ubuntu 14.0.4

I have written a parallel piece of shell code which will take a list of tables and dump them all in parallel into the mysql instance. Normally the mysqldump is reading from a local slave into a development machine.

nb: the vagrant machines run on a mix of windows and mac machines. With it being a virtual machine, i am making the assumption this isn't an issue.

The parallel code is as follows :

```
for tbl in `cat /tmp/tables.txt`
do
(
    mysqldump  -h x.x.x.x -u user -ppassword --port=3306  -C --quick --lock-tables=false SourceDB $tbl | mysql -u root -ppassword targetDB
    echo "$tbl done"
) &
done
wait
```

When running this in our production environment it works and the dump is faster than doing a linear mysqldump of the whole DB. This has lead me to believe that the above shell code is correct. However we do not get the same speed increase on local machines, it actually increases. I thought this could be something to do with load on either machine.

On production servers:

- parallel mysqldump of DB : 12mins
- single mysqldump of DB : 26mins

On Vagrant machine:

- parallel mysqldump of DB : 1hr 50mins
- single mysqldump of DB : 49mins

To eliminate the local slave, I ran the same above parallel shell code but instead of piping into the mysql instance, I saved it to disk as .sql files. One for each table. This was very faster, dumping the whole DB in 7mins. This meant that problem was not in the mysqldump part but in mysql application. I further proved this by then taking them .sql files from disk and feeding them into mysql using the same parallel method above. Again it ran at around 2hrs. So slower.

Can anyone help with this, or point me in the right direction. ?
I am making the assumption it is something to do with mysql config, but cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options I would try

- do not commit on every transactions (not sure but sometimes it seems to be the default mode, probably there's setting but not sure where it is) : add `SET autocommit=0;` before importing and `COMMIT;` when you're done
  With this option, not sure you can do export/import in oneline
- try tweaking the following parameters (applies only if you're using InnoDB)

  ```
  innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
  innodb_log_file_size = 256M
  innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
  ```

  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` parameter should also have a large value

  you can read [more about those parameters from doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html)

Comment: thanks fred. i'll give it a go and see if it improves. test may take a while ! ...or not if it works ;)